# Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power
>   of Thor.

Now **is that a correct sentence** to start with?

Does that strictly mean, *'when somone is worthy, then he can hold the hammer and posses the power'*?

**Or**

Can this sentence also mean, *'Hammer can be held by anyone but only if he is worthy, he shall possess the power'*?

Comment: Looks to me like the second meaning. **Whosoever** is not restrictive, but their worthiness is.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical in early modern English. It is marginal in current English.

The sentence in current English would be something like

> Anybody who holds this hammer, if they are worthy, will have the power of Thor.

It says nothing about whether there are restrictions on who may hold the hammer.

Comment: That version sounds far more awkward to me than the original.